# How to access HTML elements within an Angular service

Tags: html, angular, rxjs

My **app.component** includes a component **comp1**.

**comp1.component.html** includes a button defined as shown below

```
<button #myButton (click)='function()'> Temporary </button>
<button #myButton2 (click)='function2()'> Temporary2 </button>
```

In **comp1.component.ts** i define a ViewChild as follows:

```
@ViewChild('myButton') myButton !: ElementRef;
@ViewChild('myButton2') myButton2 !: ElementRef;
```

I have a service called **nlp-service** within which i would like to reference `myButton` and `mybutton2` so that i can call the `click()` event. My reasoning for doing the click through a service is because the service will be used to mainly trigger clicks on different buttons based on the input i provide to the service. So which buttons i click will be dependent on the service.

I am unable to refer to the `myButton` in the service.
Any solutions or rather any other approaches that are better suited for this will be well appreciated. I am extremely new to Web Dev and Angular so would like a thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

Because of nature of templates in angular, you can not have access to elements in the template until `ngAfterViewInit` hook, so one of the way to solve this problem is to call `nplService` in `ngAfterViewInit` and set buttons elemenets

```
export class Component {

  @ViewChild('myButton') myButton !: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('myButton2') myButton2 !: ElementRef;

  constructor(
     private nplService: NplService,  
  ) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.nplService.setButtons({
      myButton: this.myButton,
      myButton2: this.myButton2, 
   })
  }

}
```

Comment: In doing this do i have to declare the method `setButtons()` in the service ?
If so would the methods take the same attributes as the ones being passed through this method call ?

Comment: you should add `setButtons` method to your service, and yes, it's better to pass object like in component